# Media Query não está funcionando

Tags: media-queries

Eu estou usando **media query** e quando tento redimensionar a guia do navegador, a página não fica responsiva, continua a mesma.

**Meu código design responsivo:**

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

p{
    padding: 10px;
}

h3{
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.topo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
}

.cidade{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and(min-width:500px) and (max-width:800px){
    .cidade{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and(max-width:500px){
    .cidade{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="topo">
    <h1>Guia Turistico</h1>
</div>

<div class="cidade">
    <h3>Cidade 1</h3>
    <p>skdfjhuf ygsfhdjsghdfjsfgdjhsg fjhsgfjsfg hjhsfgjsf ghjsfghdjs fghjsfghjsfg hjs fghjsfghjsfgh jsfghjsfhjsfghjhsfgdjhsfg jsghfjsd fghjsdfghjs dfgjsfgsjfghj fghsjdfg hsjfghsjfgh sjfghjsfghj sfghjhfgdjhfgj sfghjsgh fjsghfjsghfjsf ghjsfghjsfghjhs fgjsghfjsghf jsghfjsfgjh sjdfghsj fgjsfgh sjdg fjs fghdsj fghs gfjs fhjsf</p>
</div>

<div class="cidade">
    <h3>Cidade 2</h3>
    <p>skdfjhufygsfhdjsghdfj sfgdjhsgfjhsg fjsfgh jhsfgjsfghjsfghd jsfghjsfghjsf ghjsfgh jsfghjsfghj sfgh jsfhjsfg hjhsfgdjh sfg jsghfjs dfghj sdfghjsdfgj sfgs jfghjf ghsjd fghsjfg hsjfg hsjfghj sfghjsfghjhfgdjh fgjsfghjsghfj sghfjsg hfjsfghj sfg hjsfghjhsf gjsghfjs ghfjsghfj sfgjh sjdfghsj fgjsfgh sjdg fjs fghdsj fghs gfjs fhjsf</p>
</div>

<div class="cidade">
    <h3>Cidade 3</h3>
    <p>skdfjhufy gsfhdjsgh dfjsfgdj hsgfjhsgfj sfghj hsfgjsfghjsfgh djsfg hjsfgh jsfghjsfg hjsfg hjsfghjsfghjsfhjsf ghjhsfgdjh sfgjsghfjs dfghjsdfghjs dfgjsfg sjfghjf ghsjdfghs jfghsjfg hsjf ghjsfghj sfghjhfg djhfgj sfghjsghfjsg hfjs ghfjsfghjsf ghjsfgh jh sfgjsgh fjsgh fjsghfjsfgjh sjdfghsj fgjsfgh sjdg fjs fghdsj fghs gfjs fhjsf</p>
</div>

<div class="cidade">
    <h3>Cidade 4</h3>
    <p>skdfjhufy gsfhdjsgh dfjsfgd jhsgfj hsgf jsfghjh sfgjsfghj sfghdjsf ghjsfg hjsfghjs fghjsfg hjsfg hjsfghjsfh jsfghjh sfgdj hsfgjs ghfjsdfg hjsdfghj sdfgjsfg sjfghj fghsjdfghs jfghsj fghsjfgh jsfg hjsfgh jhfgdjhfgjs fghjsg hfjsghf jsghfjs fghjsf ghjsfghjh sfgjsghf jsg hfjsgh fjsfgjh sjdfghsj fgjsfgh sjdg fjs fghdsj fghs gfjs fhjsf</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Veja se o seu código Html contém essa linha: **`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`**

Comment: Coloquei e ainda continua o erro...

Answer (score 0):

Bem simples, não estava funcionando porque, você não adicionou um espaço (`' '`) nos primeiros `and` após o `screen`.

**Antes:**

```
@media only screen and(min-width:500px) and (max-width:800px){
    .cidade{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and(max-width:500px){
    .cidade{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**Depois:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width:500px) and (max-width:800px){
    .cidade{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
    .cidade{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

p{
    padding: 10px;
}

h3{
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.topo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
}

.cidade{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:500px) and (max-width:800px){
    .cidade{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:500px){
    .cidade{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class="topo">
    <h1>Guia Turistico</h1>
</div>
<div class="cidade">
    <h3>Cidade 1</h3>
    <p>skdfjhuf ygsfhdjsghdfjsfgdjhsg fjhsgfjsfg hjhsfgjsf ghjsfghdjs fghjsfghjsfg hjs fghjsfghjsfgh jsfghjsfhjsfghjhsfgdjhsfg jsghfjsd fghjsdfghjs dfgjsfgsjfghj fghsjdfg hsjfghsjfgh sjfghjsfghj sfghjhfgdjhfgj sfghjsgh fjsghfjsghfjsf ghjsfghjsfghjhs fgjsghfjsghf jsghfjsfgjh sjdfghsj fgjsfgh sjdg fjs fghdsj fghs gfjs fhjsf</p>
</div>

<div class="cidade">
    <h3>Cidade 2</h3>
    <p>skdfjhufygsfhdjsghdfj sfgdjhsgfjhsg fjsfgh jhsfgjsfghjsfghd jsfghjsfghjsf ghjsfgh jsfghjsfghj sfgh jsfhjsfg hjhsfgdjh sfg jsghfjs dfghj sdfghjsdfgj sfgs jfghjf ghsjd fghsjfg hsjfg hsjfghj sfghjsfghjhfgdjh fgjsfghjsghfj sghfjsg hfjsfghj sfg hjsfghjhsf gjsghfjs ghfjsghfj sfgjh sjdfghsj fgjsfgh sjdg fjs fghdsj fghs gfjs fhjsf</p>
</div>

<div class="cidade">
    <h3>Cidade 3</h3>
    <p>skdfjhufy gsfhdjsgh dfjsfgdj hsgfjhsgfj sfghj hsfgjsfghjsfgh djsfg hjsfgh jsfghjsfg hjsfg hjsfghjsfghjsfhjsf ghjhsfgdjh sfgjsghfjs dfghjsdfghjs dfgjsfg sjfghjf ghsjdfghs jfghsjfg hsjf ghjsfghj sfghjhfg djhfgj sfghjsghfjsg hfjs ghfjsfghjsf ghjsfgh jh sfgjsgh fjsgh fjsghfjsfgjh sjdfghsj fgjsfgh sjdg fjs fghdsj fghs gfjs fhjsf</p>
</div>

<div class="cidade">
    <h3>Cidade 4</h3>
    <p>skdfjhufy gsfhdjsgh dfjsfgd jhsgfj hsgf jsfghjh sfgjsfghj sfghdjsf ghjsfg hjsfghjs fghjsfg hjsfg hjsfghjsfh jsfghjh sfgdj hsfgjs ghfjsdfg hjsdfghj sdfgjsfg sjfghj fghsjdfghs jfghsj fghsjfgh jsfg hjsfgh jhfgdjhfgjs fghjsg hfjsghf jsghfjs fghjsf ghjsfghjh sfgjsghf jsg hfjsgh fjsfgjh sjdfghsj fgjsfgh sjdg fjs fghdsj fghs gfjs fhjsf</p>
</div>
```